# jquery script to retrieve select value on click: works in Firefox, does not in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

vatshal here; I am using a jquery script in which I am getting the current value of a select box on mouse click; it works on Mozila Firefox but doesn't work in Internet Explorer

onclick in IE shows previous value from the select box id

```
<select>
         <option>value1</option>
         <option>value2</option>
</select>
```

if we are clicking on value2 then jquery gets the value of the first element, but it is working on mozila firefox only; jquery code is given  below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $("#multiple").click(function(){
        var a=$("#multiple").val();
        $("#to").val(a);
    });
});
</script>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event, and also use `this` to refer to itself inside the click handler, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#multiple").change(function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    $("#to").val(a);
  });
});
```

If you want to update on both events, use [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) like this:

```
  $("#multiple").bind('click change', function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    $("#to").val(a);
  });
```